# select from subquery criteriaBuilder

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

Could someone tell me an example of how you can make a Hibernate query with a join to a subquery using criteriaBuilder

Here is a simple example:

```
select idSchool, name from user left join (select idSchool from student where age < 15) as NewTable on idSchool = idSchool
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Hibernate Query Language HQL or JPA Query Language JP QL, both don't support joining a subquery. Subqueries can only occur on SELECT or WHERE clauses in Hibernate (and not on the FROM clause). This rule also applies to CriteriaQuery.

See related posts:

- [Hibernate Subqueries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries)
- [JPA Subqueries](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#bnbvl)

Alternatively, you can execute that as a native SQL query.